# Cocoa pods terminal utf-8 encoding

Tags: bash, cocoapods, macos-catalina, appcode

I am using IntelliJ AppCode for my project.
When I try to use cocoadpods from AppCode's terminal, I get the following warning:

> WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
>      Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
>
> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

I am using bash as my shell in AppCode (is zsh by default) and my Mac's terminal uses bash, too (was zsh).
I can execute pod commands just fine within the Mac's terminal.

I have also added the file .profile in my home dir and added the line

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and tried to close AppCode and even restarted my mac. but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: git any solution?

Comment: Same here, `locale` shows proper LANG but still get the error

Comment: It seems that `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` alone isn't enough, you have to set

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6333#issuecomment-866591220

Comment: Anybody here , I trapped with this bug almost 12 hours pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the env vars mentioned by @saschpe in Preferences > Tools > Terminal in "Environment Variables". Works for me, also in Fish shell

[image: AppCode Terminal Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

- Open Terminal in android studio
- Type **open ~/.zshrc** (or **open ~/.profile** if you don't use zsh)
- It looks like that LANG="en_US.UTF-8" isn't enough, so you might have to set following as well, write follwoing code in the file and save it

  ```
    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
    export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
  ```
- Open the again Terminal and type **source ~/.zshrc** and type **locale**
- Now run pod install, this will works

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING/TESTED on** - July 2023
| CHIP - MAC M2
| MacOS  - Ventura 13.4

What worked for me?

**Step -1 :** Uninstall Ruby using brew:

```
brew uninstall ruby --force
```

**Step -2 :** Uninstall all CocoaPods files.
List all cocoapods version using following command

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
```

Start uninstalling all the versions of cocoapods from the list shown on the terminal one by one.
In my case 8 different versions like following were listed

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-plugins

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-search

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-trunk

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-try
```

**Step 3:** Close the terminal {not just the window} totally.

**Step 4:** Start a new Terminal for the system to adapt to changes
And now install cocoapods using following brew command.

```
brew install cocoapods
```

**That's it...** call "**kdoctor**" on the new terminal and everything should work cocoapods error should be removed.

---

If you still get any error then.
**ADDITIONAL CHECK** call command

```
which ruby
```

If the resulting output is -

> /usr/bin/ruby

Then call this command-

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Restart the terminal and check again, it should be resolved.
Hope it helps...